# Using Grapher on GIN application with GinModuleAdapter

Tags: java, guice, gwt-gin

I've been trying to use [Grapher](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=Grapher) on my GIN project. But trying to create an Injector to give the InjectorGrapher has not been working.

Right in the first line of my code:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector( new GinModuleAdapter( new MyGinModule() ) );
```

it crashes with

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: should never be actually called
at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.adapter.GwtDotCreateProvider.get(GwtDotCreateProvider.java:43)
at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
at com.google.inject.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:56)
at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:200)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:194)
at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:194)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:176)
at com.google.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:113)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:92)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
at com.me.myself.Grapher.main(Grapher.java:20)
```

What gives?

Comment: I would be interested to do that too. Can you share how your main() was made? What do you bind views to, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: My module had the following line which caused GinModuleAdapter to choke (seems to be a bug):

```
 bind(Foo.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

Removing "asEagerSingleton" caused everything to work. But since that's not what I wanted, I converted it into this, which also worked.

```
@Provides @Singleton
Foo getFoo() {
    return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: Wow, so is there no way to do singletons without writing a provider for every single one?

Comment: I've run into the same issue, you can work around it by adding an interface, and bind the interface to the class. Only then I was able to bind it as a singleton. In this case: bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();

Comment: I had a similar problem, but not with an EagerSingleton. I had a bind(Messages.class).in(Singleton.class) where Messages was a concrete class.

Comment: Is this bug reported on the GIN issue tracker ?

Comment: I created an issue since I could not find it in the issue tracker:  http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=198